# static to static url rewrite with htaccess with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress site with its own .htaccess automatically generated (because I'm using permalinks), than, my web-admin has configured apache to redirect any third level domain to my site, ie :

`http://lol.example.com` redirects to `http://example.com`

and than `.htaccess` with permalinks rules does the rest.
Now I want to write a rule in the `.htaccess` file that, when a user types a specific third level domain, redirects to a specific subfolder of my site, ie:

`http://sprock.example.com/` redirects to `http://example.com/mysprockfolder/`

I know my question might sound weird, but I've never done this before so I'm quite confused.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with that regex in my `.htaccess`:

Right before this comment (just in case you have WordPress installed):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
```

I've added the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?thirdlev\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/myfolder/ [R=302,L]
```

with a 302 redirect, everything is good!

Answer (score -1):

it would be much easier for you to just go to your ftp manager and make a subdomain forward to a link. Or, you can make a redirect using php.

when redirecting make sure to add the `http://www.` or it will think you want to redirect to a part of your page on the site, also make sure that your subdomain has its own folder with its own files and images.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Something's not clear anyway, what's the ftp manager all about in this? I've not understood your hint

Comment: never mind, you should just put a php re-direct, and in html i think it's called header->redirect or something

Comment: If you use godaddy, there is a ftp manager, please specify the site you host your website is